# How to preview an HTML email in various email clients before sending it. PHP/Javascript

Tags: php, jquery, email, email-templates, litmus

I have developed a web app which is sending HTML email using PHP. I would like to let the user be able to see what the email will look like in various email clients (Outlook/Gmail etc) before sending it out.

I searched, but I could not find any plugins that would let me do this.

I found the Litmus email preview API which would work, but it is too expensive. Is there any website that has a similar API for a cheaper price or free that I can use? Or is there any way I can do this myself without the need of some other website.

Comment: Did you try Googling it?

Comment: Yes and I wrote in the question that the only thing I found was the Litmus API which charges quite a bit of money to use.

Comment: The only way I see of doing this is having virtual machines for each device, rendering the email, taking screenshots and sending back to the web app. I read somewhere that how litmus does it (if not then maybe my knowledge is old).

Answer (score 0):

To send bulk emails to clients, I use "poMMo" (https://github.com/soonick/poMMo), it allows you to view the email and even receive an email test, before sending it to the clients.

Comment: poMMo doesnt work on the latest PHP versions but i have heard its good for sending.